# To show pop-up on screen after call ends in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, background-process, android-phone-call

How to make a flutter app work always in the background, so that after a call ends, I  can show a pop-up on the screen(similar to truecaller app).
How to implement this in dart?

Comment: do you have some code?

Comment: @spycbanda, No I am trying to learn this process, So I did not have any code regarding this.

Answer (score -2):

You can checkout Alert Dialog here
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html

Comment: my question is not about alertdailog.
it is about showing an alertdailog on the mobile screen even if the app is terminated ( i.e particularly after making a call)